# While trying to open Logcat, DeviceMonitor: Adb rejected connection to client '1468': closed - existing solu

Tags: android, android-studio, adb, android-logcat

At present, I am using only emulator to run my application in Android Studio.

Logcat used to work fine before. Of late, while running emulator, when choosing Alt+6 to view Logcat, getting this message

> DeviceMonitor: Adb rejected connection to client '1468': closed

Went through this link 
[Android: Adb rejected connection to client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23794089/android-adb-rejected-connection-to-client) and tried out the solution therein. ie. in Run / Edit Configurations, put the fully qualified class name of the launcher activity in LAUNCHER field. Still the error is not rectified.

Would appreciate help on this as I am new to Android and getting struck in environmental issues as a result of which I am unable to make use of Logcat to test real application.

Comment: I was able to get Logcat up however this error message is still appearing not sure what implications will this have?