# Logcat doesnot show errors

Tags: android, logcat

When I click on the share button of my App, a message shows Unfortunately has stopped. But, this doesn't cause the app to crash. I am able to share my file. The logcat doesn't show any errors. The following is what my logcat displays .

```
03-28 15:10:23.585  18455-18455/com.example.akn.play_music D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 208K, 2% free 17001K/17240K, paused 28ms, total 28ms
03-28 15:10:25.165  18455-18455/com.example.akn.play_music D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 142K, 2% free 17003K/17312K, paused 11ms, total 12ms
03-28 15:10:25.175  18455-18464/com.example.akn.play_music D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 3K, 2% free 17576K/17892K, paused 11ms, total 11ms
```

Comment: just restart adb and restart eclips then check

Comment: i have tried adb kill-server and  abd start-sever on the terminal. I have also tried restarting my android studio

Comment: This is what my adb log says DeviceMonitor: Adb rejected connection to client '17261': closed

Comment: check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23794089/android-adb-rejected-connection-to-client

Comment: from taskmanager end the adb task and connect your device again to system and try

Comment: i have tried ending adb task . I have restarted my android studio. Re-Installed the drivers. No luck so far