# App not installing in Emulator, showing "No Debuggable Processes"

Tags: android, android-emulator

I'm building an app in Android Studio. After some time the app stopped reflecting the progress of the building development. I then uninstalled the app from the emulator and it has not installed although build is successful every time. I built the apk for the app and dragged it to the emulator. App is installed but does not start. Is there anything to make it work?

Have done the following:

1. enabled and disabled Instant Run
2. enabled and disabled ADB integration
3. restarted Android Studio  added debug{debuggable true} to buildTypes in the app gradle even though it is not advisable

[Device Monitor says "ADB rejected shell command (ls -l /)" and "Adb connection Error:EOF"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fVlF3.png)

Thank you

PS:
Android Studio version 3.0.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally solved it. Thanks to [Andy Boot's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/95396/andy-boot) answer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23794089/android-adb-rejected-connection-to-client/45249922#45249922). In short:

1. I went to Run->Edit Configurations->Android App->app
2. The Launch droplist had 'Default Activity' selected. I changed that to 'Specified Activity'
3. I then filled in 'MainActivity' in the Activity field, which has the 'LAUNCHER' intent in the Manifest file.

And that got my app running once again on the emulator ;)

Thanks, everyone.

Answer (score 0):

Check **"minSdkVersion"** in App Gradle. if it is less than the Emulator which you have then it will not install or run on it. Make sure **"minSdkVersion"** should be greater than or equal to Emulator API level.

Comment: The minSdkVersion is 15 and I use Nexus 5X API 26 which matches the compileSdkVersion. So that's not the problem. Thanks for trying to help out.

Answer (score 0):

In Android studio Go to "Build Variant" tab and then change your application build Varian to Debug.

Comment: Thanks, Anbarasu. I have tried both the release and debug variants but to no avail.

Comment: Connect your real android device and check wether it is showing or not. if yes problem is from your emulator and try creating new one.

Answer (score 0):

Do the following if you are facing like Gradle Build finished successfully while running app but app is not installed in Mobile or Android Emulator then follow the steps

[image: STEP-1][image: STEP-2][image: STEP-1]

In 3rd image 'Deploy' and 'Launch' options should be selected as shown in picture. Apply settings and click OK. YOU DONE.. HAPPY CODING.